# base.Invoke with delegates

Tags: c#, reflection

I am invoking a delegate and I'm not very informed about how it works and I have compilation errors because of it (Compiler Error CS1660).  This is the code I have for it:

```
 base.Invoke( delegate {
            bool flag = (((this.layerPickPlaceProcess != null) && (this.robotComponent != null)) && ((((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Ready))) && ((((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Ready));
            this.cmdManualPlace.Enabled = flag;
        });
```

Comment: Reflector is a tool that will show you decompiled assemblies - the technology is called  **reflection**.

Comment: Im familiar with Reflector, just not with delegates and the reflection maybe didnt spit out the code correctly?

Answer (score 8):

add `(Action)`:

```
 base.Invoke( (Action)delegate {
            bool flag = (((this.layerPickPlaceProcess != null) && (this.robotComponent != null)) && ((((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Ready))) && ((((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Ready));
            this.cmdManualPlace.Enabled = flag;
        });
```

this is because Invoke accepts `Delegate` which is not (sic!) a delegate type as far as the C# compiler is concerned. A delegate type should define a call signature, while `Delegate` does not and is just a common ancestor. The expression `delegate { ... }` has type... try to guess... *anonymous delegate* (if it was a method it would be *method group*). They are not delegate types either! But they can be implicitly converted to a delegate type that has a matching signature. And delegate types can be implicitly converted to `Delegate`.

`Action` is: `public delegate void Action();`

simply, chains:

- `Anonymous method` → `Delegate`: no conversion exists
- `Anonymous method` → `Action`: implicit conversion if signature matches
- `Action` → `Delegate`: implicit conversion (`Action` is descendant of `Delegate`)

Combine them:

- `Anonymous method` → `Action` → `Delegate`: it works!

Comment: I need at least one parameter for Action<>. do i dare try Action<Delegate>?

Comment: @mookie there is delegate type `Action` without params

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// MethodInvoker is also acceptable.
Action action = delegate
        {
            bool flag = (((this.layerPickPlaceProcess != null) && (this.robotComponent != null)) && ((((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.layerPickPlaceProcess.State) == StateEnum.Ready))) && ((((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Idle) || (((StateEnum) this.robotComponent.State) == StateEnum.Ready));
            this.cmdManualPlace.Enabled = flag;
        };

base.Invoke(action);
```

You have to tell the complier a *specific* delegate-type to use; there could be any number of delegate-types that are compatible with an anonymous method.

You might find this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy74she2%28VS.80%29.aspx) helpful, although it doesn't mention why the C# compiler doesn't consider `System.Delegate` to be a delegate-type, which is the real problem here.

Comment: Not wrong, but would be nice to mention one of the two syntaxes that allows this to be written in one statement without a temporary variable.